# Scraping data from a Table using Python BeautifulSoup and request

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape API Directory on the Web from this webpage https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis

the list of APIs is in form of a table on the web page. But out of about 30 APIs on the first page, my code only returns two APIs which are the first and the second.

I will be grateful if any expert in this community can go through the code as well to tell me what is wrong with it.

**Here is the code I have written**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis"  # url to be scraped.
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'views-table cols-5 table'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
master_list = []
for row in table_body.find_all('tr'):
    master_list.append(row)

print(len(master_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the table is in its rows, so `td` is the tag you should be targeting.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis")
rows = BeautifulSoup(
    response.text, 'html.parser'
).find(
    'table',
    {'class': 'views-table cols-5 table'},
).find_all("tr")

table = [[i.getText(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("td")] for row in rows[1:]]

print(len(table))
```

This gives you table's rows for the first page. There are `25 items`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `pandas` to read the table:

```
import requests
import pandas
from lxml import html
data = html.fromstring(requests.get("https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis").text).xpath("//table")[0]
data = pandas.read_html(html.tostring(data))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the source code and the part you are willing to extract.

```
<td class="views-field views-field-pw-version-title">
   <a href="/api/google-maps">
           Google Maps API
   </a>
   <br/>
</td>
```

In this case we have a `<td>` tag with the `class` `views-field-pw-version-title`

The `find_all` method you extract these parts of the source code.
And the `get_text` method with `strip="True"` will extract only the text without space before and after

A simple solution would be :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webpage = requests.get("https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find_all('td', class_='views-field-pw-version-title')

i = 1
for line in data:
    print(f" {i} : {line.get_text(strip=True)}")
    i += 1
```

Output

```
1 : Google Maps API
2 : Twitter API
3 : YouTube API
4 : Flickr API
5 : Facebook API
6 : Amazon Product Advertising API
7 : Twilio API
8 : Last.fm API
9 : Twilio SMS API
10 : Microsoft Bing Maps API
11 : del.icio.us API
12 : Google App Engine API
13 : Foursquare API
14 : Google Gadgets API
15 : DocuSign Enterprise API
16 : Amazon S3 API
17 : Google AdSense API
18 : GeoNames API
19 : Wikipedia API
20 : Box API
21 : Amazon EC2 API
22 : LinkedIn API
23 : Bing API
24 : Instagram Graph API
25 : Yelp Fusion API
```